# Templateview in django has gone error "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'form_file' "

Tags: python-3.x, django

This is my view.py file

```
class UploadTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'reports/from_file.html'
```

This is my urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('save/', create_report_view, name='create-report'),
    path('', ReportListView.as_view(), name='main'),
    path('from_file/', UploadTemplateView.as_view(), name='form-file'),
    path('<pk>/', ReportDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('upload/', csv_upload_view, name='upload'),
    path('<pk>/pdf/', render_pdf_view, name='pdf'),
    
]
```

When I try to access my page it cost an error "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'form_file'
The only way to fix it is by changing the pathname to number. How can I define pathname as a string

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the type of a *path converter*, Django will assume that you meant `<str:…`, so `<pk>` will match with *all* strings, not only numerical ones.

You can restrict it to `<int:…>` and thus fire the `csv_upload_view` only when it does not match a number:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('save/', create_report_view, name='create-report'),
    path('', ReportListView.as_view(), name='main'),
    path('from_file/', UploadTemplateView.as_view(), name='form-file'),
    path('upload/', csv_upload_view, name='upload'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ReportDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/pdf/', render_pdf_view, name='pdf'),
    
]
```

In your template you also made a mistake for the URL: it is `from_file`, not `form_file`, you thus should either update the `path(…)`, or the link in the template.

Comment: sorry, I make a mistake spelling pathname but in the original code I spell from-file but it got an error when I try to reach with page  "reports/from-file" I received an  error "field id expect number but got from-file" This is the only page i can't fixed it

Comment: hey, I can fix it now sorry Willem. I make a spelling mistakes on URL. that is why I got an error